# Show a single character as it is typed on a separate label?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a row of labels that have been programmatically instantiated, they are stored in an NSMutableArray. They don't currently contain any data. What I'm trying to do is make it so that when a user types in a character it is automatically displayed in the labels. I'm not sure how to do this. I know how to access the labels I have created [MyArray ObjectAtIndex:0] and so on, but how could I make it so that when a user types on the keyboard it formats the text (I have code for formatting) and then just appears on screen.

I need help putting each character on the screen as it is typed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I have a textfield (it's hidden) and the keyboard comes up by button. If that helps. :)

Thank you in advance :).

Comment: You have number of label so when you text on textfield which label want to gets updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    UITextField *tf;
    [tf addTarget:self action:@selector(editingChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

- (void)editingChanged:(UITextField *)textField {
  _myHiddenLabel.text = textField.text;
}
```

Comment: This is a much simpler solution than using notifications as shown in the currently accepted (and flawed) answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add observer when Text inside UITextField changes and then access your labels and add text to it...

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(changeLabelsMethod:)
               name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification 
    object:myHiddenTextField];
}


-(void)changeLabelsMethod:(UITextField*)txtField
{
    Static int i=0;

    if(i<[MyArray count])
    {
    UILabel *lbl=[MyArray ObjectAtIndex:i];
    lbl.text=txtField.text;
    }
    else
      return
    i++;
}
```

EDIT: Refer **Eugene's** answer for **right approach**

Comment: You do realize this code will crash the application because of the static `i`, that will eventually become bigger than the array's count?

Comment: This answer is only half complete. You need to remove the observer too. This should be done in the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` delegate method. Better yet, don't use any notifications and instead use the solution in Eugene's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get notified every time a character is typed if you set your viewController as delegate to your hidden textField and implementing [UITextFieldDelegate Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (IBAction)textFieldValueChanged {
            NSString *strLastChar = [txtSearch.text substringFromIndex:txtSearch.text.length-1];
            UILabel *lblCurrent = [arrSearch objectAtIndex:intCurrentLblNo];
            [lblCurrent setText:strLastChar];
            intCurrentLblNo++;
    }
```

take intCurrentLblNo as global variable and set intCurrentLblNo = 0; in viewdidload method

and set it...

```
    [txtSearch addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldValueChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

in viewdidload method